# Export Pdf from html in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, jspdf

I want to export pdf from html in angular 6. So, I'm using `jspdf` library. But I can't giving styling like color and background color. How can I achieve this? **(If is there any other free library from `jspdf`, I can use it)** You can see demo from below link.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-urzyet?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**.ts file**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild('reportContent') reportContent: ElementRef;

    downloadPdf() {
    const doc = new jsPDF();
    const specialElementHandlers = {
      '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
      }
    };

    const content = this.reportContent.nativeElement;

    doc.fromHTML(content.innerHTML, 15, 15, {
      'width': 190,
      'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });

    doc.save('asdfghj' + '.pdf');
  }
}
```

**.html file**

```
<div #reportContent class="p-col-8 p-offset-2">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td style="color: red;background-color: blue;border:solid;">1111
      </td>
      <td style="border:solid;">2222
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<button pButton type="button" label="Pdf" (click)="downloadPdf()">Export Pdf</button>
```

Comment: You can use `doc.setFillColor(0, 0, 0)` to set background color and `doc.setTextColor(255)` to set color

Comment: I've voted +1 because it is quite good question in fact... yet I don't have any answer myself. Openslide seems to do it but I don't know how it works https://github.com/OpenSlides/OpenSlides

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminCaure. I didn't understand why one person downvoted this question.

Comment: But, I want from html. Not with typescript code. Because in real scenario there will be a lot of cell. `doc.addHtml` is working good with styling. But in `doc.addHtml`, pdf quality is very poor. @Bharathkumarkamal

Answer (score 2):

```
    captureScreen() {
        const pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
        const promises = $('.pdf-intro').map(function(index, element) {
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                html2canvas(element, { allowTaint: true, logging: true })
                    .then(function(canvas) {
                        resolve(canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0));
                    })
                    .catch(function(error) {
                        reject('error in PDF page: ' + index);
                    });
            });
        });

        Promise.all(promises).then(function(dataURLS) {
            console.log(dataURLS);
            for (const ind in dataURLS) {
                if (dataURLS.hasOwnProperty(ind)) {
                    console.log(ind);
                    pdf.addImage(
                        dataURLS[ind],
                        'JPEG',
                        0,
                        0,
                        pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth(),
                        pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight(),
                    );
                    pdf.addPage();
                }
            }
            pdf.save('HTML-Document.pdf');
        });
    }
```

With this, we have to import jsPDF and html2Canvas to the code

```
    import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
    import * as html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
```

for this, you have to do npm install the following

```
    npm install jspdf --save
    npm install --save @types/jspdf
    npm install html2canvas --save
    npm install --save @types/html2canvas
```

With this add the following in the angular.json file inside the scripts tag

```
    "node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js"
```

Inside the component.html add code like this for example:

```html
<div>
  <input type="button" value="CPTURE" (click)="captureScreen()" />
</div>
<div class="pdf-intro">HTHML content</div>
<div class="pdf-intro">HTHML content</div>
<div class="pdf-intro">HTHML content</div>
<div class="pdf-intro">HTHML content</div>
```

with this code add css how you would normally add in component.css , it would be rendered.

Hope, this solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jsPDF` and `dom to image` package to export HTML div with `id='dashboard'`.

Install package

```
import * as domtoimage from 'dom-to-image';
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
```

TS file

```
domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById('dashboard'))
    .then(function (blob) {
        var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', [$('gridster').width(), $('gridster').height()]);
        pdf.addImage(blob, 'PNG', 0, 0, $('gridster').width(), $('gridster').height());
        pdf.save(`${that.dashboardName}.pdf`);
    });
```

HTML

```
<gridster id='dashboard'></gridster>
```

Answer (score 0):

html2canvas will resolve your issue. Update your code like below.

```
downloadPdf() {
const doc = new jsPDF();
const content = this.reportContent.nativeElement;
html2canvas(content).then(canvas => {
        const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        // Few necessary setting options
        const imgWidth = 208;
        const pageHeight = 295;
        const imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
        const doc = new jspdf('p', 'mm');
        let heightLeft = imgHeight;
        let position = 0;

        doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
        heightLeft -= pageHeight;
        while (heightLeft >= 0) {
            position = heightLeft - imgHeight;
            doc.addPage();
            doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
            heightLeft -= pageHeight;
        }
        // Generated PDF
        doc.save('asdfghj' + '.pdf');
    });
```

}

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Consider reading this article on [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  In addition to the code you've provided, try to give some explanation on why and how this fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> [https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/convert-html-to-pdf-using-angular-6/][1
>                   npm install jspdf
>                   And to install html2canvas package, use given npm command.
>                   npm install html2canvas
>                   When we are done with the installation part, it's time to import it into our component using the import statement.

```
            > import * as jspdf from 'jspdf';      import html2canvas from
            > 'html2canvas';

                <div id="content" #content>  
            <mat-card>  
                <div class="alert alert-info">  
                    <strong>Html To PDF Conversion - Angular 6</strong>  
                </div>  
                <div>  
                <input type="button" value="CPTURE" (click)="captureScreen()"/>  
                </div>  
            </mat-card>  
            </div>  
            <div >  
            <mat-card>  
                <table id="contentToConvert">  
                    <tr>  
                    <th>Column1</th>  
                    <th>Column2</th>  
                    <th>Column3</th>  
                    </tr>  
                    <tr>  
                    <td>Row 1</td>  
                    <td>Row 1</td>  
                    <td>Row 1</td>  
                    </tr>  
                    <tr>  
                    <td>Row 2</td>  
                    <td>Row 2</td>  
                    <td>Row 2</td>  
                    </tr>  
                    <tr>  
                    <td>Row 3</td>  
                    <td>Row 3</td>  
                    <td>Row 3</td>  
                    </tr>  
                    <tr>  
                    <td>Row 4</td>  
                    <td>Row 4</td>  
                    <td>Row 4</td>  
                    </tr>  
                    <tr>  
                    <td>Row 5</td>  
                    <td>Row 5</td>  
                    <td>Row 5</td>  
                    </tr>  
                    <tr>  
                    <td>Row 6</td>  
                    <td>Row 6</td>  
                    <td>Row 6</td>  
                    </tr>  
                </table>  

            </mat-card>  
            </div>  

                import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef ,ViewChild} from '@angular/core';  
            import * as jspdf from 'jspdf';  
            import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';  

            @Component({  
            selector: 'app-htmltopdf',  
            templateUrl: './htmltopdf.component.html',  
            styleUrls: ['./htmltopdf.component.css']  
            })  
            export class HtmltopdfComponent{  
            public captureScreen()  
            {  
                var data = document.getElementById('contentToConvert');  
                html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {  
                // Few necessary setting options  
                var imgWidth = 208;   
                var pageHeight = 295;    
                var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;  
                var heightLeft = imgHeight;  

                const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')  
                let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'mm', 'a4'); // A4 size page of PDF  
                var position = 0;  
                pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight)  
                pdf.save('MYPdf.pdf'); // Generated PDF   
                });  
            }  
            } 

                new JsPDF(  
                Orientation, // Landscape or Portrait  

                unit, // mm, cm, in  

                format // A2, A4 etc  
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this way [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-html-to-pdf-example)
In you demo use in this way

```
import {jsPDF} from 'jspdf';


public downloadPDF() {
   const doc = new jsPDF();
   .....
}
```