# How to create PDF with contents from an Angular view?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, pdf, export-to-pdf

I have an Angular app that uses [ngx-charts](https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-charts) to render some graphs, for example:

[image: Demo chart]

Now I want to export this view and its graphs to a PDF file, but at the moment I'm not sure how to tackle this.

Is there a way to export this view's HTML to PDF, or are there other ways to produce PDF files based on a view?

**ADDITIONAL QUESTION**: imagine I have to render the view and generate the PDF backend side, without user interation, how would you handle this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53388758/export-pdf-from-html-in-angular-6 try this.

Comment: @aviboy2006 Thanks, so basically the way to do it is: first capture the view as a screenshot to a canvas, and then convert the canvas to PDF, is my understanding correct?

Comment: You can use jsPDF and dom to image package to export HTML div with id='dashboard'

Comment: I will give it a try! Thanks!

Comment: @aviboy2006 meanwhile, added an extra question to my topic, related to how to produce such PDF based on a view without user interation, so in an asynchronous worker process on the server. I guess I have to take a different approach for this one.

Comment: Yes you have to take approach like parallel processing or once page load or api gives result hit another function to download.

Answer (score 0):

By far you have the best chances with this library: [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)

or you can try to do something from this code :

```
print(){  
  var canvas = document.getElementById(id) as HTMLCanvasElement;
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
  let popupWin,printContents;
  popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
  popupWin.document.open();
  popupWin.document.write(`
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>${title}</title>
        <style>
        </style>
      </head>
  <body width="100%" height"="100%" onload="window.print();window.close()"><img src="${dataURL}" width="600px" height="auto"></body>
    </html>`
  );
  popupWin.document.close();
  }
```

in short create a canvas and print that out (and save as pdf)